# hql query formation

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to construt a hql query like

```
select PLAN_ID from "GPIL_DB"."ROUTE_PLAN" where ASSIGNED_TO 
      in ('prav','sheet') and END_DATE > todays date
```

I am doing in this way but getting an error in setting parameters

```
s=('a','b');
Query q = getSession().createQuery("select planId from RoutePlan where assignedTo in REG ");
if(selUsers != null) {
   q.setParameter("REG", s);
}
```

where i am doing wrong? Please help in executing this hwl based query having in clause

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign the parameter list in the query. Also note the brackets around the parameter because it is an 'in' query.

```
Query q = getSession()
      .createQuery("select planId from RoutePlan where assignedTo in (:REG) ");
if(selUsers != null) {
   q.setParameterList("REG", s);
}
```

You can read more about how to use parameters in HQL in [the hibernate reference](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-querying), but this is the relevant example pasted from there:

```
//named parameter list
List names = new ArrayList();
names.add("Izi");
names.add("Fritz");
Query q = sess.createQuery("from DomesticCat cat where cat.name in (:namesList)");
q.setParameterList("namesList", names);
List cats = q.list();
```